# Get the minimum of a generic List<T>, T extends Comparable

Tags: list, java-stream, min, comparator

`current.getValues();` returns a List of the `generic T`

```
List<T> val = current.getValues();

return val.stream().min(????)
```

What do I have to fill in the brackets at return `val.stream().min(????)`? How do I get the Comparator of `T`?

I don't know what to enter. First time working with generics. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements in the list implement `Comparable` interface, and you need the minimum element according to their *natural ordering*, you can provide [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder()) as an argument of `min()`.

```
return val.stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```